# Arm assembly adding variables

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

Information first, I am using keil uvision (as a student). I am trying to replicate an expression, `result = (x-y) + z` (mind you I'm just tackling the parentheses first).

I am have loaded the registers with two variables x and y to R0 and R1 respectively.
I know you also need to then store the contents OF those register to new ones, getting the value in them.  However, when I step though the code, I see that it isn't doing that.

My add operation line also is returning no values, and I'm confused as to why. Here is the code:

```
    AREA RESET, DATA, READONLY
    EXPORT __Vectors
__Vectors
    DCD 0x20001000
    DCD Reset_Handler ; reset vector
    ALIGN
    AREA Demo, CODE, READONLY
    ENTRY
    EXPORT Reset_Handler
 Reset_Handler

    LDR R0, =X
    STR R1, [R0]
    
    LDR R2, =Y
    STR R3, [R2]
    
    ;LDR R2, =Z
    ;STR R2, [R2]
    
    SUB R4, R1, R3
    MOV R6, #1
    ADD R3, R3, #1
    
X DCD 7
Y DCD 2
;Z DCD 4

stop B stop
    END
```

Comment: `STR` stores to memory.  Your code begins by assigning to `X` and `Y` the contents of `R1` and `R3`.  I believe this is not what you want.  Try `LDR` instead.

Comment: @fuz thank you, I figured it was a silly mistake, this was the answer I needed!

Comment: what does the disassembly show?  that X DCD 7 between the add and before the stop could put data in the code path and not stop properly or go off into the weeds...